# Global variable not defined with circular import and async/await

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

In my project I have two modules: `main` and `api`. `main` imports `api` to perform certain API calls, and `api` imports `main` to use a logging function defined there. The code looks something like this

Inside `main` module:

```
import asyncio
import multiprocessing
import api

def log(msg):
    print(multiprocessing.current_process().pid). # prints out a different pid than the main process, I don't understand why
    with lock: # raises NameError: name 'lock' is not defined
        some_log_func(msg)

async def main():
    global lock

    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    
    data = await api.query()

    # ... some multiprocessing stuff


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Inside `api` module:

```
import main

async def query():
    main.log('Querying...') # causes the NameError shown above
    # do some stuff
```

As mentioned, running the `main` module raises `NameError: name 'lock' is not defined`. I'm using a `multiprocessing.Pool` later in the `main` module but at the point when this error occurs, it's running in the main process and the pool hasn't been initialized yet.

Where am I going wrong here?

It's also worth noting that my `log` function is used in the worker processes as well, so I've been printing out the pid of the current process for debugging, and though I haven't spawned any processes yet, when the `log` function gets called it prints out a pid which doesn't belong to the main process (I'm guessing async/await uses separate processes internally?). If it does use separate processes, then that would make sense since the global variable won't be defined in that child process, but if so, is there a way for the child process to inherit the lock?

Comment: `main` executes up to `import api` at which point `api` begins executing. When that gets to `import main`, `main` begins to execute. That’s your circular import. The easiest fix is probably to define common things like `log` in another module that doesn’t import from things that import it.

Comment: Yeah, don't do circular imports and conditionally defined globals, you're almost inviting bugs like this to happen.
Instead of circular imports, arrange your imports like a dependency tree with branches, no loops. You can pass functions as arguments in Python so sharing functions between modules is pretty easy.

Comment: @dirn yeah I realized the circular import, but I'm not understanding why when main starts executing again it's in a different process

Comment: @BatWannaBe I thought about that, the reason I didn't do a separate module is because the log function depends on some globals that are inherited from the parent process (like the lock) so I didn't want to have to pass those variables every time I make the call to log

Comment: Also @dirn to clarify, I'm not actually getting a circular import error since I'm not doing `from module import whatever`, I was just explaining that the issue happens when I do the circular import, but the actual issue is that `main.log` is somehow running in a new process

Comment: Ah, yeah, and I suppose the answer to your question is that you say to use the global `lock` but it isn’t yet defined. You need to define it outside `main` for there to be a global.

Comment: @dirn oh shoot yeah, I intended for that to go in the entry code not my `main` function. But anyway I'm running into a different issue now saying that the module has no attribute `log`...I'm also having separate issues with not being able to log from the child processes so I think I'm better off just reworking a solution with a separate logging module like you guys mentioned and a queue to pass messages up to the parent. Thanks for the help!